# Disabling the home button, gives me an error

Tags: android, listview, android-homebutton

I know this has been asked a few times, but I am having some problems with actually using the solution provided.
I want to disable access to the home button on a particular activity.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I think that my issue is with the first statement under the `OnCreate` method but idk.

This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);
    background2= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    final ListView theListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Intent calledActivity=getIntent();
    final List pe=calledActivity.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Caller1");

    String []s =new String[pe.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<pe.size();i++)
    {
        s[i]=(String)pe.get(i);
    }

    final ListAdapter theAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pe);
    theListView.setAdapter(theAdapter);
    final int cnt=1;

    theListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String s1 = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            pe.remove(s1);
            if(pe.size()==0)
            {
                Intent goback;
                goback = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goback);``
            }
            ((BaseAdapter)theAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();



        }
    });



    }

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
}
```

logcat:

```
01-25 11:00:42.486    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-25 11:00:42.506    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1e8ed0, tid 1090
01-25 11:00:42.526    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-25 11:00:42.536    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
01-25 11:00:42.686    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-25 11:00:42.706    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 11:07:14.726    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 268K, 14% free 2751K/3180K, paused 133ms, total 163ms
01-25 11:07:15.286    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 90K, 15% free 2814K/3280K, paused 222ms, total 267ms
01-25 11:07:15.366    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.509MB for 635812-byte allocation
01-25 11:07:15.626    1090-1099/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 13% free 3433K/3904K, paused 263ms, total 263ms
01-25 11:07:16.048    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 13% free 3430K/3904K, paused 284ms, total 300ms
01-25 11:07:16.096    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 3.982MB for 500416-byte allocation
01-25 11:07:16.216    1090-1099/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 11% free 3919K/4396K, paused 116ms, total 116ms
 01-25 11:07:16.636    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
 01-25 11:07:16.646    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
 01-25 11:07:16.696    1090-1090/com.example.epiclapser.noprocrastinate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Window type can not be changed after the window is added.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1435)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
        at   android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.relayout(IWindowSession.java:835)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:5034)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1399)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @user3249477 There you go

Comment: You can't call `Window#setType` on the window once it's been attached.  You're calling it in `onAttachedToWindow`.

Comment: Could you please elaboreate, @DeeV

Comment: Now I understand your question and I sincerely hope this is not possible. Just think how frustrating it could be for some users.

Comment: No, you see the once you exit from the second screen you are once again free to use the phone as you wish, android does not allow for an App Block unfortunately